# How to find lenght of a line in file( Python)

Tags: python, csv

I'm reading a csv file, and I need a function to read from the same position as in my main loop.

Since f.tell() is not working, I wanted to use f.seek(position) and update my position according to the line read. For that, I need length of the line in bytes I guess.

Unfortunately, this little program gives me crazy output, some lines are good but most of them are not, I don't know which part am I missing?

```
def some_function(position):
    f = open("eurusdfunctions.csv","r")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    f.seek(position)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        break
    f.close()

file = open("eurusd.csv","r")
position = 0
reader1 = csv.reader(file)
for line in reader1:
    time_price,open_price,high_price,low_price,close_price,volume_price=line
    # position = position + len(time_price) + len(open_price) + len(high_price) + len(low_price) + len(close_price) + len(volume_price)
    some_function(position)
    position = position + sys.getsizeof(line)
file.close()
```

Btw, eurusd and eurusdfunctions are same files just different names. They look something like this:

```
01.01.2020 00:00:00.000,1.12154,1.12154,1.12154,1.12154,0
01.01.2020 01:00:00.000,1.12154,1.12154,1.12154,1.12154,0
01.01.2020 02:00:00.000,1.12154,1.12154,1.12154,1.12154,0
01.01.2020 03:00:00.000,1.12154,1.12154,1.12154,1.12154,0
01.01.2020 04:00:00.000,1.12154,1.12154,1.12154,1.12154,0
```

Comment: Are those two names *really* the same file?  Or are they simply two different files with the same data?  Either way, why are you reading the same data twice?  This appears to be a severe design error.  Read the data *once*, and process that original copy as needed.

Comment: I need to read data backwards in every iteraton, so this is necessary in my case, these are 2 files with same data.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you're reading the file backwards.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Your function's `for` loop never iterates; I don't see the logic of your position computation -- what have you done to validate its accuracy?  Your CSV readers and `seek` functions seem to be working against each other.  Again, show us your internal diagnostic tracing.

Comment: i was planning on reading it backwards but i can't do it without knowing exact position where to seek. My future development of a function doesn't have to do anything with this problem

Comment: Solved the problem, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

len(list_items) didn't count for any commas, so adding that to position with just +7 for 5 commas and \n solved the problem...

```
file = open("eurusd.csv","r")
position = 0
reader1 = csv.reader(file)
for line in reader1:
    time_price,open_price,high_price,low_price,close_price,volume_price=line
    some_function(position)
    position = position + len(time_price) + len(open_price) + len(high_price) + len(low_price) + len(close_price) + len(volume_price) + 7
    # position = position + len(line)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Since f.tell() is not working

Don't use a csv reader, use `.readline` then `tell` will work.

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        wheraminow = f.tell()
        print(f'wheraminow:{wheraminow}')
        time_price,open_price,high_price,low_price,close_price,volume_price = line.strip().split(',')
```

---

If you have blank lines, wrap the split in a try/except

```
....
    while True:
       ...
        try:
            time_price,open_price,high_price,low_price,close_price,volume_price = line.strip().split(',')
        except ValueError as e:
            print('empty line')
```